# Count how many times an item from an array is used in php

Tags: php, arrays, count

I'm trying to write a code, and could use a little help. Lets say I have a test file with 5 colors. I only want each color to be used 10 times.

EDIT: Edited the code to reflect my setup some more. Mainly need to make a function that I can call upon to return 1 of my 5 colors that hasn't been used more then 10 times.

```
$colors = array_map("trim", file("colorlist.txt")); //loads all my colors

// echos all my colors
foreach($colors as $color){
  echo ''.$color;
}

function checklimit($string){

BS CODING......
$currentcolor = getcolor();

}


function getcolor() {
 $totalpercolor = 10;
  If all $colors $totalused = $totalpercolor {
      exit;
  } else {
  shuffle($colors)
  Return a single color who's $totalused < $totalpercolor;
  $color's $totalused = $totalused++
  }
}


$result = mysql_query("SELECT whatever FROM $table_name WHERE doesntmatter IS NULL");
while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($results)){
  $data = checklimit($string);
}
```

Org:

```
$colors = array(file("colorlist.txt"));

$i = 1;
foreach($colors as $color){
  if color[i] <= 10 {
  var color[i] = 0++;
  i++;
  } else {
     If all colors = 10 { 
         end;
     } else {
           start loop over, get new color
     }
  }
}
```

I'm sure this isn't the right way to go about it. So any help would be great.

Comment: Could you var_dump($colors) so i can see you array structure?

Comment: you might want to create a function to do this rather than a foreach loop, then again, its hard to understand what youre trying to do based on your question.

Comment: this is a terrible code .. and not a valid php script ...

Comment: the colorlist has 1 color per line.

Comment: LOL@ baba, thanks! If I knew the correct coding, I wouldn't have posted the question here...

Comment: edited my org post to reflect how I plan to use this.

Answer (score 0):

```
foreach($colors as $color){
    if($color_num[$color])
     $color_num[$color]++;
    else $color_num[$color] = 1;
 }
```

At the end of the loop you have a $color_num array with count of each color. Now you can add some in-loop checks, eg. `if($color_num[$color] >= 10) ...`

-- But indeed you should post valid code, so we can provide constructive answers.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply have

To load the colors

```
$colors = array_map("trim", file("log.txt"));
printf("%s\n", implode(",", $colors)); //red,blue,orage,black,purble
```

To reuse the colors you can use `modulus`

```
$total = count($colors);
$limit = 10;
for($i = 0; $i < $limit; $i ++) {
    echo $colors[$i % $total], PHP_EOL;
}
```

or Infinite Iterator

```
$limit = 10;
$iterator = new InfiniteIterator(new ArrayIterator($colors));
foreach(new LimitIterator($iterator, 0, $limit) as $color) {
    echo $color, PHP_EOL;
}
```

Both would return

```
red
blue
orage
black
purble
red
blue
orage
black
purble
```

Answer (score 0):

I have no idea what you want, so i'll just answer three cases you might be wanting:
If you need to print each collor 10 times and then move on to the next color

```
$colors = array_map("trim", file('colorlist.txt'));
foreach ($colors as $color)
{
    for ($i=1; $i<=10; $i++)
        print $color . PHP_EOL;
}
```

Will output:

```
blue
blue
blue
blue
blue
blue
blue
blue
blue
blue
green
green
green
green
green
green
green
green
green
green
(the other 3 colors)
```

If you need to output the colors in order:

```
$colors = array_map("trim", file('colorlist.txt'));
for ($i=1; $i<=10; $i++)
{
    foreach($colors as $color)
        print $color . PHP_EOL;
}
```

Will output you:

```
blue
green
red
pink
gray
blue
green
red
pink
gray
```

And if you need to output the colors randomly, and each color must appear 10 times:

```
$colors_file = array_map("trim", file('colorlist.txt'));
foreach ($colors_file as $color)
    $colors[] = array($color, 0);

while(!empty($colors))
{
    $index = rand(0,count($colors)-1);
    echo $colors[$index][0] . PHP_EOL;
    if (++$colors[$index][1] == 19)
    {
        unset($colors[$index]);
        $colors = array_values($colors);
    }
}
```

Will output:

```
pink
red
red
blue
gray
blue
green
blue
gray
gray
green
red
red
```